# How can I edit a line of text in a file using Python?

Tags: python, xml, file

I have a bunch of xml files and I need to edit one line in each, and the edit should be adding "_n" in the middle somewhere.
Also, in each file the line is different, so I can't just hard-copy a text line, it needs to edit the current existing line.

I tried the following:

```
with open("file_name", "w") as name:
            for line in name:
                if "Test.xml" in line:
                    name.write("Test_n.xml")
```

The thing is, there's more text before and after the "Test.xml" in the line.
What I can't figure out is how to cut the line where I need before the **_n** in order to insert it in the middle there.

By the way, it's an XML file, as far as it matters...

Comment: It would be useful if you shared your exact data. I would think `regex` is the way to go if your data changes. If there’s something simpler, you could get away with using `str.split`.

Comment: The line is essentially a path, and from each time only one of the sub-directories change (meaning part of the string). The path leads to a file "Test.xml" and I need to change it to "Test_n.xml" instead. Does that makes it clearer maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to make a new list of lines you want, editing the chosen line, and finally writing back to the file:

```
with open(file, 'r') as file:
    lines = [line.replace('Test.xml', 'Test_n.xml') 
             for line in file
             if 'Test.xml' in line]

with open(file, 'w') as file:
    for line in lines:
        file.write(line)
```

Comment: Doesn't work... the file remains the same with no apparent changes.
Also I can't just write the 'Test_n.xml'. It's more like:
Swap the line "words words words THING_TO_REPLACE word" with "words words words THING_TO_REPLACE_n word".
It's in the middle of the text, and I need to edit the same text file, EXACTLY in the same place.